# Korn Shell path not found

Tags: linux, path, ksh

I have a problem with a script ksh (mainScript) that call other scripts.

mainScript:

call ./folder1/folder2/first.sh

error that I get:

```
 ./folder1/folder2/first.sh not found [No such file or directory]
```

I verify with ls -l /folder1/folder2/first.sh and I see that the script exist.

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `.` from your path and also provide execute permission on the file then you will be able to run the script. like

`[root@localhost#] chmod +x /folder1/folder2/first.sh`

then run

`[root@localhost#] /folder1/folder2/first.sh`

Also, you can run your script using following:

`ksh /folder1/folder2/first.sh` or `sh /folder1/folder2/first.sh` or `bash /folder1/folder2/first.sh etc`